# How to use jQuery plugins in typescript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx, spfx-webparts

OK, I've seen many people struggling and different approaches on how to do this but I've been cracking my head and can't get it done.

I need to implement this photo gallery in a SPFx web part and use it on a modern page.

This is the idea:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/js/external/_oldies/jquery-1.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/js/external/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/js/external/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/js/sliderkit/jquery.sliderkit.1.9.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/js/sliderkit/addons/sliderkit.counter.1.0.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/js/sliderkit/addons/sliderkit.imagefx.1.0.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/js/sliderkit/addons/sliderkit.delaycaptions.1.1.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {

        $(".delaycaptions-01").sliderkit({
            circular:false,
            mousewheel:false,
            keyboard:true,
            shownavitems:4,
            auto:false,
            panelfxspeed:500,
            delaycaptions:{
                delay:500, 
                position:'bottom',
                transition:'sliding',
                duration:300,
                easing:'easeOutExpo'
            }
        });
    }

</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/css/sliderkit-core.css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/css/sliderkit-demos.css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/css/sliderkit-site.css" media="screen, projection" />


<div class="sliderkit photosgallery-captions delaycaptions-01">
    <div class="sliderkit-nav">
        <div class="sliderkit-nav-clip">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow" title="[link title]"><img src="../lib/images/photos/mini/sample-01.jpg" alt="[Alternative text]" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow" title="[link title]"><img src="../lib/images/photos/mini/sample-02.jpg" alt="[Alternative text]" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow" title="[link title]"><img src="../lib/images/photos/mini/sample-03.jpg" alt="[Alternative text]" /></a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderkit-btn sliderkit-nav-btn sliderkit-nav-prev"><a rel="nofollow" href="#" title="Previous line"><span>Previous line</span></a></div>
        <div class="sliderkit-btn sliderkit-nav-btn sliderkit-nav-next"><a rel="nofollow" href="#" title="Next line"><span>Next line</span></a></div>
        <div class="sliderkit-btn sliderkit-go-btn sliderkit-go-prev"><a rel="nofollow" href="#" title="Previous photo"><span>Previous photo</span></a></div>
        <div class="sliderkit-btn sliderkit-go-btn sliderkit-go-next"><a rel="nofollow" href="#" title="Next photo"><span>Next photo</span></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderkit-panels">                      
        <div class="sliderkit-panel">
            <a href="../lib/images/photos/sample-01.jpg" title="[title]"><img src="../lib/images/photos/sample-01.jpg" alt="[Alternative text]" /></a>
            <div class="sliderkit-panel-textbox">
                <div class="sliderkit-panel-text">
                    <h4>sample-01.jpg</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sliderkit-panel-overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderkit-panel">
            <a href="../lib/images/photos/sample-02.jpg" title="[title]"><img src="../lib/images/photos/sample-02.jpg" alt="[Alternative text]" /></a>
            <div class="sliderkit-panel-textbox">
                <div class="sliderkit-panel-text">
                    <h4>sample-02.jpg</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sliderkit-panel-overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderkit-panel">
            <a href="../lib/images/photos/sample-03.jpg" title="[title]"><img src="../lib/images/photos/sample-03.jpg" alt="[Alternative text]" /></a>
            <div class="sliderkit-panel-textbox">
                <div class="sliderkit-panel-text">
                    <h4>sample-03.jpg</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sliderkit-panel-overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to do things like this:

```
SPComponentLoader.loadScript('../lib/js/external/_oldies/jquery-1.3.min.js', 
    { globalExportsName: 'jQuery'}).then((jQuery: any): void => {
        SPComponentLoader.loadScript('../lib/js/external/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js', 
         { globalExportsName: 'easing' }).then((jQuery: any): void => {    
          SPComponentLoader.loadScript('../lib/js/external/jquery.mousewheel.min.js', 
           { globalExportsName: 'mousewheel' }).then((jQuery: any): void => {     
            SPComponentLoader.loadScript('../lib/js/sliderkit/jquery.sliderkit.1.9.2.pack.js',
             { globalExportsName: 'sliderkit' }).then((jQuery: any): void => {
              SPComponentLoader.loadScript('../lib/js/sliderkit/addons/sliderkit.counter.1.0.pack.js',
                { globalExportsName: 'counter' }).then((jQuery: any): void => {    
                SPComponentLoader.loadScript('../lib/js/sliderkit/addons/sliderkit.imagefx.1.0.pack.js', 
                 { globalExportsName: 'imagefx' }).then((jQuery: any): void => {     
                  SPComponentLoader.loadScript('../lib/js/sliderkit/addons/sliderkit.delaycaptions.1.1.pack.js',  
                  { globalExportsName: 'delaycaptions' }).then((jQuery: any): void => {      
                    jQuery(".delaycaptions-01").sliderkit({
                        circular:false,
                        mousewheel:false,
                        keyboard:true,
                        shownavitems:4,
                        auto:false,
                        panelfxspeed:500,
                        delaycaptions:{
                            delay:500, // must be equal or higher than panelfxspeed
                            position:'bottom',
                            transition:'sliding',
                            duration:300, // must be less equal or higher than panelfxspeed
                            easing:'easeOutExpo'
                        }
                    });


                  });    
                });    
              });
            });   
          });    
        });
      });
```

But this is so hard. And it would be so easy if I could do it a as a basic html page...

This is the plugin page:

http://www.stg-online.net/web/script/slider/sliderkit_en.html

Please help

Comment: I got it working. I simplified this using only 2 external libraries instead of 7. It turned out they are not that important. Then I kind followed kin these steps: https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc

Comment: I had to change this file: JQuery.d.ts and add this line: sliderkit(options?: any, callback?: Function) : any;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the official docs about how to add jquery library to SPFx web part, you may take a reference:

- [Add an external library to your SharePoint client-side web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/add-an-external-library#load-a-script-from-a-cdn)
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part

And There is a quick way to add Jquery:

- Create a project with jQuery using the [PnP SPFx Yeoman generator](https://pnp.github.io/generator-spfx/)

[image]

More references:

- [Why bundling external frameworks in SharePoint Framework is a bad idea](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/bundling-external-frameworks-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-bad-idea/)